# How can I save validation accuracy and validation loss using model.fit() method in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've fitted a TensorFlow model using the following code:

```
H = model.fit(
aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
validation_data=(testX, testY),
validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
epochs=EPOCHS)
```

I then saved the history H to a file using pickle:

```
with open('trainHistoryDict', 'wb') as file_pi:
    pickle.dump(H.history, file_pi)
```

Later, in another file, I opened the history file and tried to plot the accuracy:

```
history = pickle.load(open('trainHistoryDict', "rb"))


acc = history["accuracy"]
val_acc = history["val_accuracy"]

loss = history["loss"]
val_loss = history["val_loss"]

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), acc, label="Training Accuracy")
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), val_acc, label="Validation Accuracy") #error line 1
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.title("Training and Validation Accuracy")

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), loss, label="Training Loss")
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), val_loss, label="Validation Loss") #error line 2
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.title("Training and Validation Loss")

plt.savefig("plot.png")
plt.show()
```

When I run it, however, it shows an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Face Mask Project\result_plotter.py", line 28, in <module>
plt.plot(range(EPOCHS), val_acc, label="Validation Accuracy")
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3019, in plot
return gca().plot(
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1605, in plot
lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 315, in __call__
yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 501, in _plot_args
raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (20,) and (1,)
```

If I comment out the two offending lines marked above ("error line 1" and "error line 2", it works, but the generated plots show only accuracy and loss (not val_acc and val_loss).

To try and understand what was happening, I ran the following code:

```
print("Accuracy:", acc)
print("Validation Accuracy:", val_acc)
print("Loss:", loss)
print("Validation Loss:", val_loss)
```

My output was as follows:

```
Accuracy: [0.9096505641937256, 0.9752079844474792, 0.9828618764877319, 0.9825291037559509, 
0.9861896634101868, 0.9885191321372986, 0.9891846776008606, 0.9856905341148376, 
0.9875208139419556, 0.9896838665008545, 0.9906821846961975, 0.9908486008644104, 
0.9893510937690735, 0.9900166392326355, 0.9923461079597473, 0.9926788806915283, 
0.9915141463279724, 0.9925124645233154, 0.9926788806915283, 0.9911813735961914]
Validation Accuracy: [0.9774983525276184]
Loss: [0.2912612855434418, 0.09379503130912781, 0.06693552434444427, 0.056832149624824524, 
0.04721272364258766, 0.03781645745038986, 0.03927478939294815, 0.04021407663822174, 
0.040082670748233795, 0.03416448459029198, 0.030927633866667747, 0.02979424223303795, 
0.03364679962396622, 0.033807653933763504, 0.027459658682346344, 0.025368137285113335, 
0.026647908613085747, 0.025594033300876617, 0.02399270236492157, 0.0274509247392416]
Validation Loss: [0.09666801244020462]
```

From this, it seems as though only the last value each of val_loss and val_acc was saved to the history object.

From my research online, however, it seems as though defining validation_data in the model.fit() method should be enough to save the entire set of values for val_loss and val_acc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the length of `testX` (and `testY`)?

Comment: @tromgy testX is an RGB array of images as  [[ 0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686]
   [ 0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686]
   [ 0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686]
   ...
   [ 0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686]
   [ 0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686]
   [ 0.99215686  0.99215686  0.99215686]]]] and so on.

Comment: testY is a 2D binary array produced by one hot encoding, as [[0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]]

Comment: @tromgy the length of both testX and testY is 1511.